# How to use foreach to add values into every array within an array?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I am currently designing a program that creates a revision timetable for students. I'm trying to create a function that goes through a 2d array and inserts subjects into a random place in that array , ie maths in slot 12 on monday then moves onto the next day.I have both the subjects with assigned number of hours per week set as variables from a previous page I just need help selecting each array within the main array. Here is my 2darray, bear in mind ive only included the first 3 arrays to save space even tho there are 7.

```
$Timetable = array(
"0" => array      // 0 = Monday 6= Sunday
                     // 0 - 24 = horus
(
    "0" => "",
    "1" => "",
    "2" => "",
    "3" => "",
    "4" => "",
    "5" => "",
    "6" => "",
    "7" => "",
    "8" => "",
    "9" => "",
    "10" => "",
    "11" => "",
    "12" => "",
    "13" => "",
    "14" => "",
    "15" => "",
    "16" => "",
    "17" => "",
    "18" => "",
    "19" => "",
    "20" => "",
    "21" => "",
    "22" => "",
    "23" => "",
    "24" => "",
),
"1" => array
(
    "0" => "",
    "1" => "",
    "2" => "",
    "3" => "",
    "4" => "",
    "5" => "",
    "6" => "",
    "7" => "",
    "8" => "",
    "9" => "",
    "10" => "",
    "11" => "",
    "12" => "",
    "13" => "",
    "14" => "",
    "15" => "",
    "16" => "",
    "17" => "",
    "18" => "",
    "19" => "",
    "20" => "",
    "21" => "",
    "22" => "",
    "23" => "",
    "24" => "",
),
"2" => array
(
    "0" => "",
    "1" => "",
    "2" => "",
    "3" => "",
    "4" => "",
    "5" => "",
    "6" => "",
    "7" => "",
    "8" => "",
    "9" => "",
    "10" => "",
    "11" => "",
    "12" => "",
    "13" => "",
    "14" => "",
    "15" => "",
    "16" => "",
    "17" => "",
    "18" => "",
    "19" => "",
    "20" => "",
    "21" => "",
    "22" => "",
    "23" => "",
    "24" => "",
),
);
```

The expected result, is the table filled with values the user put, for example if the user had entered maths for 4 hours english for 6 and biology for 2 the array might look something like this.

```
  '$'Timetable = array(
"0" => array      // 0 = Monday 6= Sunday
                     // 0 - 24 = horus
(
    "0" => "",
    "1" => "",
    "2" => "",
    "3" => "english",
    "4" => "",
    "5" => "",
    "6" => "",
    "7" => "maths",
    "8" => "",
    "9" => "biology",
    "10" => "",
    "11" => "english",
    "12" => "",
    "13" => "",
    "14" => "",
    "15" => "",
    "16" => "",
    "17" => "",
    "18" => "",
    "19" => "",
    "20" => "",
    "21" => "",
    "22" => "maths",
    "23" => "",
    "24" => "",
),
"1" => array
(
    "0" => "",
    "1" => "",
    "2" => "",
    "3" => "",
    "4" => "",
    "5" => "",
    "6" => "",
    "7" => "",
    "8" => "",
    "9" => "english",
    "10" => "",
    "11" => "maths",
    "12" => "",
    "13" => "",
    "14" => "",
    "15" => "",
    "16" => "english",
    "17" => "",
    "18" => "",
    "19" => "",
    "20" => "",
    "21" => "english",
    "22" => "",
    "23" => "",
    "24" => "",
),
"2" => array
(
    "0" => "",
    "1" => "",
    "2" => "",
    "3" => "",
    "4" => "",
    "5" => "",
    "6" => "",
    "7" => "",
    "8" => "",
    "9" => "",
    "10" => "",
    "11" => "",
    "12" => "",
    "13" => "biology",
    "14" => "",
    "15" => "english",
    "16" => "",
    "17" => "",
    "18" => "",
    "19" => "",
    "20" => "",
    "21" => "",
    "22" => "",
    "23" => "maths",
    "24" => "",
),
);
```

Comment: Can you provide the expected result? For it is not entirely clear what you want to achieve here.

Comment: If your subarray goes from 0 to 24, don't you have 25 entries for 24h day? Shouldn't you loose "24" or you have a reason for having two entries for "midnight"?

Comment: @BozidarSikanjic It should be from 0-23 you are correct thank you

Comment: do this worked or you need more help ?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with one random integer for each level of the array:

```
$first = rand(0,6); 
$second = rand(0,23); 

$string = 'Random Subject'; 

$timetable[$first][$second] = $string;
```

Depending on how many 'Subject' you want to add, you should create an array of random Subjects and create another random variable that would select a random string from this array :

```
$subjects = ['English', 'Maths', 'Biology']; 
$subs = rand(0,count($subjects)); 

$timetable[$first][$second] = $subjects[$subs];
```

You can repeat this operations as many times as you want, or put it inside a function and repeat it on a `for`.

Comment: thank you for this, sorry for the  somewhat broad question and badly formatted code. i'll try to implement this and see if i can get it to work. i'll just need to add some error handling so that 2 subjects are placed in the same time slot but and a loop that runs until all the subjects have been placed in for the correct amount of answers.